# When a LinkedIn invitation is withdrawn, is really no message sent?

Tags: linkedin

Sometimes, I misclick and send an invitation to the wrong person on LinkedIn (mostly because the UI is sh*t on the add connection page). When I [withdraw it](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&es_sm=122&q=cancel+invite+linkedin+&oq=cancel+invite+linkedin), it says:

[image]

Is really no message sent? I thought a message was sent right away to when inviting someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*No Message will be sent to ...* here it means when you withdraw an invitation, the recipient won't be notified about it.

When we invite someone, the person gets an invitation email, but when we withdraw an invitation, the person does not get any notification or email.

[From the Help Centre](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26/~/withdrawing-an-invitation):

(See the second point of the fifth point.)

You can withdraw an invitation if the recipient hasn't taken any action.

1. Click the **Inbox icon** in the top right of your homepage.
2. Click **Sent** on the left.
3. Find an invitation without "Accepted" next to the name.
4. Click the subject line of the invitation.
5. Click **Withdraw**.

   - If the **Withdraw** button isn't there, the invitation can't be withdrawn. It may have already expired.
   - > The recipient won't be notified about a withdrawn invitation.
   - If you change your mind, you'll need the recipient’s email address to send them another invitation.

Comment: However, they will know you withdrew it! Yes, you can withdraw the invite and it no longer pops up in their notifications but, if they got the invite in their email (and, when they click "Accept," they can't), they will know! You can't rescind the email.